# Failed to find TextTransform.exe on VDI in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a C# project which is giving following error in VS2019.

```
"The "TransformOnBuildTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Exception: Failed to find TextTransform.exe
   at Clarius.TransformOnBuild.MSBuild.Task.TransformOnBuildTask.GetTextTransformExePath()
   at Clarius.TransformOnBuild.MSBuild.Task.TransformOnBuildTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()"
```

I have tried different solutions mentioned on StackOverflow:

[How to run the TextTemplatingFileGenerator on Build (VS 2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568884/how-to-run-the-texttemplatingfilegenerator-on-build-vs-2017)

I also tried installing the suggested Nuget Package, which fails getting installed in the solution with below error:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/JohnVerbiest.TransformOnBuild/

```
NuGet\Install-Package : Could not install package 'JohnVerbiest.TransformOnBuild 1.3.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'native,Version=v0.0', but 
the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ NuGet\Install-Package JohnVerbiest.TransformOnBuild -Version 1.3.2
```

I am stuck and cannot build the project and solution. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Was the "Text Template Transformation" component installed? Open the Visual Studio installer and check and if needed add the "Text Template Transformation" component.

Comment: @JonathanDodds - Thank you for responding. Yes it is installed.

Comment: If you are building at the command line, are you using a 'dev command prompt' or have you run the `VsDevCmd.bat` file? (When Visual Studio 2019 is installed, it will create a "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019" shortcut in the Start menu. The shortcut starts cmd and runs the `VsDevCmd.bat` file.  `VsDevCmd.bat` adds environment variables and modifies PATH.)

Comment: Microsoft provides MSBuild support for TextTransform - see "[Code Generation in a Build Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-in-a-build-process?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp)". Was there an issue with using this?

Comment: The `JohnVerbiest.TransformOnBuild.MSBuild.Task` task just looks in a long list of possible locations - see [`GetTextTransformExePath()`](https://github.com/johnverbiest/TransformOnBuild/blob/c7bcff8ac7596d10d18c72b07140611dd30a5a7a/JohnVerbiest.TransformOnBuild.MSBuild.Task/TransformOnBuildTask.cs#L138). The task does a weird thing by getting the running MSBuild project so it can inspect the properties in the project. If you define a `TextTransformPath` property with the path of `TextTransform.exe`, the task will use it. (But this should have been implemented as an optional task parameter.)